# Why does the loop execute only once?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following small code which manipulate tweets data. I expect my loop to iterate 10 times. However, what happens is that it **iterates only once** and then exits, *with no sign of any error* relating to MySQL or otherwise.

```
$query = "select data from tweets where `screen_name` = 'username' limit 10";
$tweetsq = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$tweets = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tweetsq);
$tweets_count = mysqli_num_rows($tweetsq);
echo $tweets_count . '<br />'; //See output

$count = 0;
foreach ($tweets as $raw_tweet) {
    $tweet = json_decode($raw_tweet);
    $tweet_id = $tweet->id_str;
    $is_reply = (isset($tweet->in_reply_to_screen_name) && strlen($tweet->in_reply_to_screen_name) > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    $is_retweet = (isset($tweet->retweeted_status) && $tweet->retweeted_status != '') ? 1 : 0;
    $entity_holder = array();
    $has_hashtag = $has_url = $has_mention = $has_media = 0;
    foreach ($tweet->entities as $type => $entity) {
        if (is_array($entity) && count($entity) < 1) {
            //continue;
        } else {
            $entity = array_pop($entity);
            switch ($type) {
                case 'hashtags' : $has_hashtag = 1; break;
                case 'urls' :  $has_url = 1; break;
                case 'user_mentions' : $has_mention = 1; break;
                case 'media' : $has_media = 1; break;
                default :

            }
        }
    }
    echo 'Updating recorde... <br />';
    $query = "UPDATE tweets SET is_reply='" . $is_reply . "' , is_retweet='" . $is_retweet . "', has_hashtag='" . $has_hashtag . "', has_url='" . $has_url . "', has_mention='" . $has_mention . "', has_media='" . $has_media . "' WHERE tweet_id='" . $tweet_id . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    var_dump($result); //See output
    $count++;
    echo '<br />';
}
echo $count;
```

**Output**:

```
10 //This is the value of $tweets_count
Updating recorde... 
bool(true) //The result of the UPDATE query
1 //The value of $count at the end of script. It SHOULD be 10
```

Comment: You're looping through `$tweets`, not `$tweetsq`. While you are echoing the count of `$tweetsq`, you're looping through `$tweets`. Have you tried echoing the count of `$tweets`?

Comment: @vanamerongen Ok. Just did `echo sizeof($tweets)` and it returned `2`! This is weird because I have more than 30 records matching the query.

Comment: Could it be because you're using http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp? Try http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) fetches **a single row** as an associative array where the key is the column name and the value is the column value. The correct way to use it would be to iterate over the result set until the fetch returns `NULL`, indicating that there are no more rows to fetch:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tweetsq)) {
    $raw_tweet = $row["data"];
    $tweet = json_decode($raw_tweet);
    $tweet_id = $tweet->id_str;
    # etc...
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it :) No screwing around with counts etc. Just fetch and do something with each result. Although I think in this instance he's looking for fetch_all

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks to both of you guys.